# To step 3 meters backward / behind

Tags: word-usage

A woman is farsighted and she is too close to the TV. She can't see what is going on TV.

For this reason:

She steps 3 meters backward to see the program better.

She steps 3 meters behind to see the program better.

Which one of these sentences is correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: They can both be correct, but they mean different things. For the basic scenario, I would say *she steps three meters back*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> She steps 3 meters backward to see the program better.

That would work.

> She steps 3 meters behind to see the program better.

Behind what? Behind the TV? She won't see the picture at all from there.